# Should we still use -webkit- and -moz- for recognised CSS3 properties?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

I am trying to clean up a CSS file and I am wondering if it is now safe to remove vendor specific properties is they have been standardized (or at least semi-standardized)?

For example should I still use

```
-webkit-border-radius
-moz-border-radius
border-radius
```

Or is it better to simply go with

```
border-radius
```

?

Comment: If you're looking to make your life easier, you can look at LESS and SASS: http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/

Comment: There will be a time when you won't have to use vendor prefixes for a lot of the prefixed properties (like `border-radius` and `opacity`), but if you want as broad support as possible, you're better off at this point with the former.

Comment: http://caniuse.com remains the best place to analyze and decide when prefixes are useful based on how many versions back you intend to support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would say stick with them. Unless you are sure X browser has been standardized. According to w3schools, all major browsers support `border-radius`, however it's not a creditable site for such information.

Why not test it out?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the property, but mostly the answer is that you should keep using the browser-prefixed versions too. It depends on the implementation status and on the actual use of various versions of browsers, rather than standardization status as such.

Check out [MDN descriptions of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference), section *Browser compatibility*. Though not authoritative and not absolutely up-to-date in all cases, they are a great reference. For example the [`border-radius` description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius) says that Firefox 4.0 and newer, Chrome 4.0, and Safari 5.0 support the standard, non-prefixed version. Older versions have very low usage now.

On the other hand, existing code should not be cleaned up. You win nothing but risk making some silly mistakes in editing code. Even though e.g. the current version Firefox ignores the prefixed property name, this does not prevent pages using it from working, provided that they also set the property using the standard name.

In contrast, for example, the very useful `hyphens` property currently has *no* support except as browser-prefixed. To take another example, `border-image` is mostly supported as browser-prefixed only, though Firefox 15 and newer and Opera also support the standard name.

There are reasons why older versions of browsers may still be used. One reason is that some application that is important in some environment might fail to work on newer versions of a browser. (Or that’s what I’ve been told when I have encountered some very old versions in use.)

Comment: Good point about not modifying legacy code - it's not good to fix things which "ain't broke". But - you should always look at dates of some suggestions - if the advice is old, check twice. I am in favour of cleaning up in these CSS files from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the former for backwards compatibility support.

```
-webkit-border-radius
-moz-border-radius
border-radius
```